# Web application developed in VS 2010 SP1 solution not working in VS 2017

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2017

I have a Legacy web application which is working perfectly in VS 2010 with service pack 1. I am trying to migrate the same solution to VS 2017.When I open the solution in 2017 and try to run it is hitting the `Application_Start` there after it goes to `Application_EndRequest`, it is never hitting the `Session_Start` event.

The error I am getting the the Application_EndRequest is

```
Session state is not available in this context.    at System.Web.HttpApplication.get_Session()
```

[image]

My web application is using `MVC` architecture.

I have tried to enable the session in `webconfig` but still no luck.

```
 <system.web>
      <pages enableSessionState="true" /> 
 </system.web>
```

web page version using is

```
  <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
```

Target framework is

```
 <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
```

Mvc version using is

```
  <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
```

`Note 1 :`I already went through most of the stack overflow questions related to this issue not nothing is solving my issue .

**Update :**

```
 protected void Application_Start()
        {

            AutoMapperConfiguration.Configure();

            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        }
void Application_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          //no code inside application end request.
        }
  protected void Session_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            try
            {
                string sessionId = Session.SessionID;

                bool dbcheck = CheckDBConnection();

            }

        catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //handle execption
            }


        }
```

Note 2: The `session_start` itself is not hitting and I am not at all assessing session in `application_start`. I have commented all code inside the application start but still the same issue is coming.

I have tried to open the same solution from VS 2015, Still the same behavior it is hitting the Application_End event, and the error in object sender is

```
Session = '((System.Web.HttpApplication)sender).Session' threw an exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException'
```

Can anyone help me to resolve the same ? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You aren't providing enough info; e.g. the code that is trying to access Session, Instead of the screenshot, post the full exception details including stack trace.  What happens if you comment out the access to `Session`in Application_EndRequest?  You may find it's concealing a different error.

Comment: give me few minutes i will share the information

Comment: @Joe added the code.

Comment: @Joe there are no exceptions i am getting in application start it run successfully and after that instead of going to session start it is going to application end state . I have placed a breakpoint in session start that it also not hitting at all .

Comment: @Joe I am not accessing session from application_start. it is simply going to application end after executing the application start. do you have any idea about this?

Comment: You are getting an exception: `Session state is not available in this context.    at System.Web.HttpApplication.get_Session()`.  You need the full stack trace of this exception to determine where in your code  it is being thrown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution. In my `webconfig` file there is a `url redirection rule` is defined that is what making the issue. It is working perfectly after commenting that

```
 <rewrite>
      <rules>
              <rule name="Redirect to https" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="SeeOther" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
```